# What is the utility of wrapping a function definition in if (TRUE == FALSE)?

Tags: r, function, if-statement, boolean-logic

While reading some code from GitHub, my head kinda exploded when I saw the `if` statement `(TRUE == FALSE)`. I wonder what is the utility of declaring it before a function.

```
if (TRUE == FALSE) {
  myfoo <- function(input_1, input_2 = 10) {
      output <- input_1 + input_2
      return(output)
  } 
}
```

The original code is located here in line 91.
https://gist.github.com/alexchinco/467325abbf11d5c8f565

Comment: Well never seen such a thing. Will wait for experts to look at this

Comment: The only possible thing I can think of is a weird way to toggle whether the function is declared or not (i.e. change the ``FALSE`` to ``TRUE`` to allow it to be declared). But this seems very roundabout.

Comment: @onyambu Yes, I believe we should wait.

Comment: I've already seen `if(FALSE)`. But not that code.

Comment: Sometimes, when I have a **if**, I temporarily do **if(FALSE)** to be sure the code inside the **if** will not be executed. I could comment the **if** block, equivalently. So maybe the coder has a similar practice, and this is just temporary.

Comment: They also spice it up here and there with a little rm(list=ls()).

Comment: The content of the `if` block looks like it generates data.  The final line saves the generated data to file.  The first line after the `if` block reads said file in.  So it looks to me like a (crude) toggle to save some time when testing/running the rest of the code.  Personally, I'd do the same thing by setting an option (or flag) and then using something like `if (option) {<generate data>} else {read data from file}`...

Comment: The `if(FALSE)` trick is sometimes seen to block code-segments temporarily for testing purposes in the development phase, especially if the used editor does not support outcommenting of code blocks. I would say that the `if(TRUE == FALSE)` is just a more visible version of this. Not worth talking about ;-) and definitely nothing that causes headaches.